# Could assignment value of variable of double type be different from print out value of that variable in Java?

Tags: java, double, floating

If I assign a variable of double equals a number. My understanding is that what this number is actually represented/stored using 1 and 0 may not be exactly the same with this number I just assigned anymore. 
So is it possible that I assign a literal value to a double variable, and then I print this variable out, the number print out is different from the liberal value???

I tried out System.out.println(123456789.123456789); the result is 1.2345678912345679E8. No difference.

Comment: Why can't you just try?

Comment: @RohitJain: How is the OP supposed to know what value might exhibit the behaviour?

Comment: @RichieHindle. Yeah right.

Comment: Yes. `System.out.println(1.0000000000000001);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here are some rules about how floating-point arithmetic works in Java:

- When you write a floating-point literal in your program, the Java compiler parses that value into a `double` with `Double.parseDouble(String)`.
- `Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(x))` is equal to `x`, with the exception of NaN, which is weird.
- `Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(string))` might be different than `string`, because `double` has limited precision. For example, `Double.toString(Double.parseDouble("3.141592653589793238462"))` will return `3.141592653589793`.  (As a corollary, `System.out.println(3.141592653589793238462)` will print out `3.141592653589793`.)
- The *exact* number stored in a `double` is neither of these numbers.  Since a `double` is stored as a binary fraction, like 1/2 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ..., a `double` cannot store decimal numbers like `0.1` exactly, since `0.1` can't be represented exactly as a sum of powers of 2.  To get the exact value stored in a `double`, you can do `new BigDecimal(double).toString()`.  For example, `new BigDecimal(0.1).toString()` returns `"0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625"`, which is the best approximation of `0.1` that is representable in a `double`.
- The number printed out by `Double.toString(x)` is the decimal number Y with the fewest digits such that `x` is the closest number to Y that is representable as a `double`.  This is why even though `0.1` is represented as `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`, `Double.toString` only returns `"0.1"`.
- If you want to store the exact value `0.1` or exact decimal values, you basically have to convert a *`String`* to a `BigDecimal`, as in `new BigDecimal("0.1")`.  As soon as you have a number as a `double`, it can't be trusted to store an accurate decimal value anymore.

Comment: You mean `new BigDecimal("0.1")` there. Using `0.1` is damage already done.

Comment: @RohitJain: No, I absolutely definitely mean `new BigDecimal(0.1)` without the quotes.  The point of that bullet point was that `new BigDecimal(0.1).toString()` tells you the exact number that is stored in the double-precision approximation of `0.1`.  (I didn't make that as clear as I could've, though; I've clarified that.)